# Missing required module in iOS framework

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-frameworks, module-map

trying to make a Swift framework which uses umbrella header to use some c code. But while importing it in the sample app, it shows the warning of missing required module.
I know it is directing the path of the module.modulemap file to the framework project rather than directing to path inside the actual framework file.

How to change this path or resolve this issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it inside a static framework you need to export your files in module.private.modulemap file. Hope this helps. See example

```
 module ModuleName {

 export *

 }
```